# Selector on HTML list's open state

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Is there a possibility to find out which container is in a list already open and which are still closed?

For the moment, I'm using `slideDown()`, `slideDown()`, and `addClass`, on divs with the specific `class="section_hdl_aktiv"`, but I want to open all other divs without these class

**Here's a piece of JS :**

```
if (state == "") {
    jQuery('#app-control-list ul li ul').slideDown();
    state = "open";
    jQuery('#app-control-list ul li').addClass("section_hdl_aktiv");
    console.log(state); 
} else if (state == "open") {   
    jQuery('#app-control-list ul li ul').slideUp(); 
    jQuery('#app-control-list ul li').removeClass("section_hdl_aktiv");
    state = "closed";   
    console.log(state);             
} else if (state == "closed") {
    jQuery('#app-control-list ul li ul').slideDown();
    jQuery('#app-control-list ul li').addClass("section_hdl_aktiv");
    state = "open";
    console.log(state);
}
```

Do someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using jQuery you can write a statement like...

```
if($('#app-control-list').is(':visible')) { ... }
```

or

```
if($('#app-control-list').css('display') == 'none')) { ... }
```

Looking at the code you posted I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do, but if you can post your html that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$("#app-control-list ul li").not("section_hdl_aktiv").each(function() {
    $(this).slideDown()
}
```

That should find all elements without the section_hdl_aktiv class and slide them down.

Comment: after your edit, this should be exactly the answer you are looking for.